# How can i create this Curved Bottom ImageView?

Tags: android

Target Image View

[image]

I want to create an image view like the one in the design. I have no idea how to go about it. I'm hoping someone can point me int the right direction. A library or what I can do to get it.

Comment: You want it to overlay your action bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this, you can use toolbar. I am suggesting you. I think, you should use ArcLayout 3rd party library. You can find in github.

Comment: I added the https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout library but it has an issue cropping the embedded image like the example in the readme.md. I'm using Glide to load the network images into the ImageView

Comment: Update. I found a library that works fine. Also called ArcLayout. https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4823

Comment: I'm so happy. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

create png image  that curved image. then set src into imageview